# unable to compile build

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, material-ui

Tell me what could be. The project was created using the create-react-app command.
package.json//

```
"name": "front",
"version": "1.0.0",
"private": true,
"proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
"dependencies": {
  "@material-ui/core": "^3.3.2",
  "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.1",
  "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
  "history": "^4.7.2",
  "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
  "material-ui": "^0.20.2",
  "react": "^16.5.1",
  "react-dom": "^16.5.1",
  "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
  "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
  "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.9",
  "react-scripts": "1.1.5",
  "react-transition-group": "^1.1.2",
  "reactstrap": "^6.3.1",
  "redux": "^4.0.0",
  "redux-api-middleware": "^2.0.0-beta.3",
  "redux-persist": "^5.0.0-beta.7",
  "redux-persist-transform-filter": "0.0.18",
  "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
},
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

I searched the net. Found nothing suitable. Plus, many solutions require a webpack configuration file. Thanks for your help!
When i use command npm run build, have this result:

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Failed to minify the code from this file: 

     ./node_modules/@material-ui/core/es/styles/withStyles.js:35 

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! front@1.0.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the front@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/rom/.npm/_logs/2018-10-28T14_41_52_597Z-debug.log
```

Comment: why use both reactstrap and material ui?

Comment: try removing these dependencies: `@material-ui/core`, `@material-ui/icons`, `material-ui`. Then, try installing only this one: `npm install @material-ui/core`

Comment: Yes you are right. I'm just learning, and installed a few extra packages in the process of creating an educational application. Now I understand this problem, thanks for your comment. As for the problems with the build, the answer below helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As following github issue suggests you should modify your imports
So your `import Button from 'material-ui/es/Button/Button';` will become `import { Button, Divider } from 'material-ui';` or other ways which doesn't include any `/es/` in import path:

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/9056